While running server.js in kubernetes pods getting errors connect ETIMEDOUT
Error connecting to the database server: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true
}
tried with changing my application host with container MySQL ip address from pods....tried with putting localhost as host, anyone able to figure it out please respond.
while running my server.js file getting below message on browser
Cannot GET /
i have checked the logs of mysql app it is connecting database correctly.
Note: i am running docker and K8s in my local system
